# Notification or Alert When "VIP" is in a list or DE to be used for a send

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

We have board members in many lists or DEs in our instance. Is there anyway to send a notification or post an alert to a sender prior to an email being sent if one of the lists or DEs they are sending to include a board member?

We have a main list for our board members, but those board members have also subscribed to many of our other email products.

Comment: You can't automatically do this "prior to an email being sent", especially since emails can be sent by many methods - Journey Builder, Automation, Guided Send, Transactional Send... But you can ensure proper QA process, so your VIPS (as well as any other recipients) don't receive emails with errors.

Comment: Nothing OOB as Lukas said. This does not answer the "prior to an email being sent", but maybe you can develop a code snippet to inject into all emails, it will basically do a lookup to check if the current subscriber is present in the list of your board members, If it's the case, log it into a DE and have an automation that runs hourly and sends an email through a verification step if the logs DE records count is greater than 0. A lot can be done to optimize this, but just dropping the raw idea here...